# Font size in text annotation when exporting QGIS layouts to PDF or JPEG?

Tags: qgis

When I try to export a map from the Layout Manager in QGIS, all the elements apart from the text annotation come through fine. These come through as tiny objects, with tiny font.

I could put labels on in the layout manager, rather than on the project window, but as far as I can see, there is no option for using the handy call-out boxes that are available in the main project window.

Comment: That's a bug in QGIS. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28121

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: It's fixed in recent versions - try upgrading

Comment: Thanks, will do. I'm on 3.4.7